# AngularJs directive return a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

The directive bellow return an object "directive". Can I return it to a function?

```
var sharedApp = angular.module("sharedApp", []);
sharedApp.directive("showAvatar", function () {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "ACEM",
        replace: true,
        template: "<h2>This is directive template of shared module</h2>"
    };

    return directive;
});
```

(Updated)For example

```
var sharedApp = angular.module("sharedApp", []);
sharedApp.directive("showAvatar", function () {
    function directive(){
        this.restrict = "ACEM";
        this.replace = true;
        this.template = "<h2>This is directive template of shared module</h2>";
    }

    return directive;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return it to a function" ???

Comment: Hi ExpertSystem. Please see my example!

Comment: It won't work like this. Why do you want to return a function ? BTW, have you read the **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)** ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you give us an example of how you want to use the directive?

Answer (score 2):

Return it to a function means do you want to return directive object from your directive to JS controller..

Define your Directive like this

```
App.directive('showAvatar', function() {
return {
    restrict : 'EA',
    scope : {
        returnFunction : '&'
    },
    controller : function($scope) {
       $scope.directive = {
        restrict: "ACEM",
        replace: true,
        template: "<h2>This is directive template of shared module</h2>"
      };
    $scope.returnFunction({data : $scope.directive});
   }
```

});

Write your directive html tag like this

```
<show-avathar return-function = "getDataFromDirective(data)">
```

And finally in your controller, declare the function getDataFromDirective()

```
$scope.getDataFromDirective = function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
```